# What subpackage name to choose for menus, dialogs, etc?

Tags: java, android

It looks like my stuff like menus, alert dialogs and other things are growing and I have a lot of classes, xml files mixed all together. I want to move these 'addons' to a separate package. What is a common name for such kind of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose the root package for your application is `com.cdnsol.app` then when you bundle all the menu, alert and other utilities in another package, it name should be `com.cdnsol.util` depicting as utility package.

Answer (score 1):

If your root package is com.stovflw.app then choose com.stovflw.app.widgets or com.stovflw.app.view.widgets